# node-soap - Proper method of calling function

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, meteor, soap-client

I know absolutely nothing about SOAP lol,  But a vital part of my software requires I use it for a particular webservice.  The documentation for the webservice was written for .net so it makes it even harder for me to understand what I need to do here.  On top of all that they require authentication.

For the connecting I do not need to authorize so I am able to retreive the describe function result.  They are as follows:

```
I20151214-09:20:20.381(-8)? Getting inside soap client creation method
I20151214-09:20:20.722(-8)? Exception while invoking method 'createSoapClient' TypeError: Cannot call method 'describe' of undefined
I20151214-09:20:20.723(-8)?     at Object.Soap.createClient (packages/zardak_soap/packages/zardak_soap.js:37:1)
I20151214-09:20:20.724(-8)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.createSoapClient (controllers/server/testFiles.js:21:1)
I20151214-09:20:20.724(-8)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (livedata_server.js:1698:12)
I20151214-09:20:20.725(-8)?     at livedata_server.js:708:19
I20151214-09:20:20.725(-8)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/packages/meteor.js:1013:1)
I20151214-09:20:20.726(-8)?     at livedata_server.js:706:40
I20151214-09:20:20.726(-8)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/packages/meteor.js:1013:1)
I20151214-09:20:20.726(-8)?     at livedata_server.js:704:46
I20151214-09:20:20.727(-8)?     at tryCallTwo (C:\Users\Media Center\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\promise\0.5.1\npm\node_modules\meteor-promise\node_modules\promise\lib\core.js:45:5)
I20151214-09:20:20.727(-8)?     at doResolve (C:\Users\Media Center\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\promise\0.5.1\npm\node_modules\meteor-promise\node_modules\promise\lib\core.js:171:13)
I20151214-09:20:21.996(-8)? Getting inside the return of the create client
I20151214-09:20:22.007(-8)? { PRIMEStandardV1_1:
I20151214-09:20:22.008(-8)?    { PRIMEStandardV1_1Soap:
I20151214-09:20:22.009(-8)?       { RunTrip: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.009(-8)?         ReverseGeocode: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.010(-8)?         FindLocationsInRadius: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.010(-8)?         FindLocationsOnRoute: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.010(-8)?         FindLocationsInState: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.011(-8)?         GetAverageDieselPriceInState: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.012(-8)?         TestRadiusGeofence: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.012(-8)?         TestRouteGeofence: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.013(-8)?         RunSimpleTrip: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.013(-8)?         Geocode: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.014(-8)?         GetTodaysUSDieselAverage: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.014(-8)?         GetTodaysCanadianDieselAverage: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.015(-8)?         GetTripDistance: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.016(-8)?         ValidateLocation: [Object] },
I20151214-09:20:22.017(-8)?      PRIMEStandardV1_1Soap12:
I20151214-09:20:22.017(-8)?       { RunTrip: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.018(-8)?         ReverseGeocode: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.019(-8)?         FindLocationsInRadius: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.021(-8)?         FindLocationsOnRoute: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.021(-8)?         FindLocationsInState: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.022(-8)?         GetAverageDieselPriceInState: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.022(-8)?         TestRadiusGeofence: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.023(-8)?         TestRouteGeofence: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.023(-8)?         RunSimpleTrip: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.024(-8)?         Geocode: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.025(-8)?         GetTodaysUSDieselAverage: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.025(-8)?         GetTodaysCanadianDieselAverage:   [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.026(-8)?         GetTripDistance: [Object],
I20151214-09:20:22.026(-8)?         ValidateLocation: [Object] } } }
```

caseless:
    I20151216-11:53:14.658(-8)?    { dict:
    I20151216-11:53:14.658(-8)?       { 'cache-control': 'private',
    I20151216-11:53:14.659(-8)?         'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-  8',
    I20151216-11:53:14.659(-8)?         server: 'Microsoft-IIS/7.0',
    I20151216-11:53:14.660(-8)?         'x-aspnet-version': '4.0.30319',
    I20151216-11:53:14.660(-8)?         'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET',
    I20151216-11:53:14.661(-8)?         date: 'Wed, 16 Dec 2015 19:40:29 GMT',
    I20151216-11:53:14.661(-8)?         connection: 'close',
    I20151216-11:53:14.662(-8)?         'content-length': '441' } },
    I20151216-11:53:14.662(-8)?   pipe: [Function],
    I20151216-11:53:14.663(-8)?   addListener: [Function: addListener],
    I20151216-11:53:14.664(-8)?   on: [Function: addListener],
    I20151216-11:53:14.665(-8)?   pause: [Function],
    I20151216-11:53:14.665(-8)?   resume: [Function],
    I20151216-11:53:14.666(-8)?   read: [Function],
    I20151216-11:53:14.666(-8)?   body: 'soap:ServerServer was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' }
    I20151216-11:53:16.716(-8)? Error: [object Object]
    I20151216-11:53:16.722(-8)? { Envelope: { Body: { Fault: [Object] } } }
    I20151216-11:53:16.723(-8)? undefined

As you can see I am able to connect.  Now the part that is trowing me off is to actually call one of these functions.  Below is the code I am using to try to call the "RunSimpleTrip". However when I console log the Result it is a huge jumble of messages that end up running the buffer out on my cmd window and I can only see back a little ways none of it making sense.

```
var url = 'http://prime.promiles.com/Webservices/v1_1/PRIMEStandardV1_1.asmx?wsdl';

        var simpleTrip = {
                            AvoidTollRoads:     false,
                            BorderOpen:         true,
                            RoutingMethod:      "PRACTICAL",
                            TripLegs:           [{LocationText: "77611"},
                                                 {LocationText: "90210"}] 
                         }

        Soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
            console.log(client.describe());
            client.setSecurity(new Soap.BasicAuthSecurity('hoperd', 'mailaaron', 'bkkyt'));
            client.PRIMEStandardV1_1.PRIMEStandardV1_1Soap.RunSimpleTrip(simpleTrip, function(err, result, raw, soapHeader) {
                //console.log("Result: ");
                console.log(result);
                console.log("Error: " + err.root);
                console.log(err.root);
                console.log(soapHeader);
                // result is a javascript object
                // raw is the raw response
                // soapHeader is the response soap header as a javascript object
            })
        });
```

From the API's documentation this is how they call the same function using .net

```
    PRIMEEnterpriseV1 PRIME = new PRIMEEnterpriseV1();

//Authorization Credentials
Credentials c = new Credentials();
c.Username = "MyUsername;
c.Password = "MyPassword";
c.CompanyCode ="MyCompanyCode";

SimpleTrip st = new SimpleTrip();
st.AvoidTollRoads = false;
st.BorderOpen = true;
st.RoutingMethod = com.promiles.PRIME.Enterprise.RouteMethod.PRACTICAL;

TripLeg[] Legs = new TripLeg[2];

//Origin
TripLeg t = new TripLeg();
t.LocationText = "77611";
Legs[0] = t;

//Destination
t = new TripLeg();
t.LocationText = "90210";
Legs[1] = t;

st.TripLegs = Legs;

//Call Function
SimpleTrip rt = PRIME.RunSimpleTrip(c, st);
```

I am hoping someone our there has a clue to this mystery for me or can point me in the right direction as to how to properly connect this this.  Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Node-soap includes the entire response object in the error which may be why the output is too big for your console. Instead of `console.log("Error: " + err);` try `console.log("Error: " + err.root);`. That may give you some more helpful information.

In your first output it looks like your initial createClient call is failing and returning a null `client` (`Cannot call method 'describe' of undefined`). What does the error from that callback look like?

Comment: I have added the 'console.log("Error: " + err.root);' and it produces the following: Error: [object Object], So I then just console.log(err.root); and it produces this: { Envelope: { Body: { Fault: [Object] } } },

Comment: But one thing I was just able to decipher from the cryptic  result message is this:  body: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'

Comment: And as for the first describe that fails this is not me calling this but appears to be being called by the client create call.

Comment: console.log uses `[Object]` on nested objects. To see all nested data use `JSON.stringify(err.root)`

Comment: { Body:
I20151216-13:24:41.435(-8)?    { Fault:
I20151216-13:24:41.436(-8)?       { faultcode: 'soap:Server',
I20151216-13:24:41.436(-8)?         faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.',
I20151216-13:24:41.438(-8)?         detail: '' } } }

Comment: So yes it is saying that it is not an object that I am passing for some reason.  Again I am stumped.  I have been playing with this for a couple days now lol

Comment: You still aren't printing out the error from the `Soap.createClient()` call which is what appears to be failing. If you want to get answers I suggest cleaning up your question.

Comment: I just did a console log of that error and it is null.  It appears that the createClient is calling the describe before a full connection is made and it fails, then when I manually call it it is connected and returns the proper info.  That isn't the problem.  The problem is the err that is being cast from the client.RunSimpleTrip function call.  It is throwing an error that 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.',

Comment: One problem I see when I look at that WSDL file is that you are passing the wrong arguments to the `RunSimpleTrip` method. Open the WSDL in your browser and search for the `RunSimpleTrip` element and you can see that it accepts two parameters `c`, and `BasicTrip`. Your `simpleTrip` variable looks like what should be in the `BasicTrip` field.

Comment: I did not know I could put that link in the browser. Like I said above I am completely clueless when it comes to SOAP and XML.  But looking through that output it appears that the 'GetTodaysCanadianDieselAverage' only requires the c so I changed my credentials variable to c and tried to call that function and I get the same error.  Any change you can mock up some code as to what you might think the correct way to call these are.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after much trial and error I was able to figure this out.  The below code works to call the SimpleTrip and return a proper response from the server.  My TripLegs arg still isn't 100% correct to what the SOAP is looking for but the code and the way to call it is.

```
var url = 'http://prime.promiles.com/Webservices/v1_1/PRIMEStandardV1_1.asmx?wsdl';
        var credentials = { Username:       "xxxxx",
                            Password:       "xxxxxx",
                            CompanyCode:    "xxxxx"
                          };

        var simpleTrip = {
                            AvoidTollRoads:     false,
                            BorderOpen:         true,
                            RoutingMethod:      "PRACTICAL",
                            VehicleType:        "Tractor2AxleTrailer2Axle", 
                            TripLegs:           [{Location: {LocationText: "77611"}},
                                                {Location: {LocationText: "90210"}}] 
                         }

        args = {c: credentials, BasicTrip: simpleTrip};

        Soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(simpleTrip);
            client.RunSimpleTrip(args, function(err, result, raw, soapHeader) {
                console.log(result);
                //console.log(err.root);
                console.log(err.root.Envelope);
            })
        });
```

Comment: Is this code enough to make a client soap call? or Do i need to make a server as they have made in documentation